# inheritance c++, getting error when creating a constructor

Tags: inheritance, constructor

[this is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JONe2.png)

[and this are the error massages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FA4KX.png)

It has to do something with the default constructors. I just don't understand what is the error about.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring a constructor for Son, but not defining it. When you create the son object in main(), it will call the constructor for son, which must be defined. Adding an empty constructor will fix this. Instead of

```
son();
```

Write:

```
son() { }
```

And your error messages will go away.